# Create connectionstring if doesnt exits

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I try to create connectionstring if the connectionstring doesnt exits. then a new connection string have to be made. I try it like this:

```
internal static string Search(string data, string customerSchema)
        {
            string result = String.Empty;

            // get search string from the data
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(data);
            XElement el = doc.Root.Element("search");
            if (el == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(el.Value))
                return ConstructFaultResponse("No search parameter found", String.Empty);

                       // var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(DbSchema.ConnectionNameSuffix);
                        var zipcodeConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DbSchema.Sfs];
                    if (zipcodeConnection == null) {
                            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings {
                        Name = DbSchema.Sfs,
                        ConnectionString = zipcodeConnection.ConnectionString,
                        ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient" //Depends on the provider, this is for SQL Server
                    });



                    }


            if (zipcodeConnection != null) {
                try {
                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(zipcodeConnection.ConnectionString)) {
                        if (el.Value.Length > 6) {
                            conn.Open();
                            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select top 1 s.street, s.town 
    from streets s 
    join Addresses a on a.streetid=s.id
    where a.zipcode=@zip and a.HouseNumber=@nr", conn)) {
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("zip", el.Value.Substring(0, 6));
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nr", el.Value.Substring(6));
                                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                                    if (reader.Read()) {
                                        XElement xResponse = new XElement("response",
                                            new XElement("straatnaam", reader.GetString(0)),
                                            new XElement("plaatsnaam", reader.GetString(1))
                                        );
                                        return xResponse.ToString();
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return ConstructFaultResponse("Unknown address", "unknown_address");
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    return ConstructFaultResponse(e.Message, "BAG_Zipcode_error");
                }
            }
```

But the problem is after this piece of code:

```
if (zipcodeConnection == null) {
                            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings {
                        Name = DbSchema.Sfs,
                        ConnectionString = zipcodeConnection.ConnectionString,
                        ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient" //Depends on the provider, this is for SQL Server
                    });
```

it doens't jump to this:

```
if (zipcodeConnection != null) {
```

Thank you

Oke, I changed to this:

```
 var zipcodeConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAG_Zipcodes"];

            if (zipcodeConnection == ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAG_Zipcodes"])
                zipcodeConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAG_Zipcodes"];

            else if (zipcodeConnection != ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAG_Zipcodes"]) {
                zipcodeConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DbSchema.DefaultConnectionName];
            }
```

But it never comes to this liine:

```
else if (zipcodeConnection != ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAG_Zipcodes"]) {
                zipcodeConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DbSchema.DefaultConnectionName];
            }
```

Thank you

I have a connectionstring like this:

```
  <add name="BAG_Zipcodes" connectionString="Password=;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=e;Data Source=" />
```

So if it has that connectionstring in the webconfig then use that one. And else use:

```
  zipcodeConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DbSchema.DefaultConnectionName];
```

Comment: because zipcodeConnection  still null, you didn't give it a value after this if (zipcodeConnection == null) {

Answer (score 0):

Your zipcodeConnection never has been set the value so it's still null.

You don't need to check if statement 2 times like you do. I suggest just do it like this

```
                    if (zipcodeConnection == null) 
                    {
                        // Set the zipCodeConnection's value
                    }

                    try {
                            using (...) {
                                         }
                        }
```

Answer your edit question here :

because your zipcodeConnection is always

```
zipcodeConnection == ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAG_Zipcodes"]
```

that's why its always jump pass

```
if (zipcodeConnection != ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAG_Zipcodes"])
```

Comment: No prop. I edit my post to answer your edit question.

Comment: Thank you Dawn, but how to  concisely? my own post. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this:

```
 var zipcodeConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAG_Zipcodes"];
            zipcodeConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DbSchema.DefaultConnectionName];

            if (zipcodeConnection == ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAG_Zipcodes"])
                zipcodeConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAG_Zipcodes"];

            if (zipcodeConnection == ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DbSchema.DefaultConnectionName]) 
                zipcodeConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DbSchema.DefaultConnectionName];
```

But can it be concisely?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I do not sure what are you trying to do but I suggest that you try to set zipcodeConnectionString if it null so you need to do something like this

```
var zipcodeConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DbSchema.DefaultConnectionName];
if (zipcodeConnection == null)
{
   zipcodeConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAG_Zipcodes"]
}
```